# Trying add two inputs in while

Tags: python, input, while-loop, is-empty, arithmetic-expressions

I'm making an arithmetic progression with python.
After the 10 first terms, I want a question with how many more terms the user wants to see. If it's 0, it will end the program. If it's not the program return the number of terms asked. And repeat until it's 0.
After the first loop, the program works, after that the program returns an empty.

```
i = int(input('Start of PA: '))
r = int(input('PA Reason:  '))
t1 = i
cont = 1
terms = 1
n1 = 0
while cont <= 10:
    t1 = t1 + r
    cont += 1
    print(f'{t1} > ', end='')
while terms != 0 :
    terms = int(input('\nHow many terms? '))
    if terms!= 0:
        while cont <= (10 + terms):
            t1 = t1 + r
            cont += 1
            print(f'{t1} > ', end='')
    else:
        print('END!')
```

[resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCgWs.png)

Edit: sorry for my english.

Comment: And what is the question? What do you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while cont <= (10 + terms):
```

is only the correct condition on the second batch of results. The next batch should be less than `20 + terms`, and so on.

Instead of adding to `terms`, you should just set `cont` back to `0` before each loop that prints the next batch of terms.

And rather than checking whether `terms` is zero twice, use `while True:` and break out of the loop when they enter `0`.

```
while True:
    terms = int(input('\nHow many terms? '))
    if terms!= 0:
        cont = 0
        while cont <= terms:
            t1 = t1 + r
            cont += 1
            print(f'{t1} > ', end='')
    else:
        print('END!')
        break
```

Or instead of using `while` loops, use `for` and `range()`

```
while True:
    terms = int(input('\nHow many terms? '))
    if terms != 0:
        for _ in range(terms)
            t1 = t1 + r
            print(f'{t1} > ', end='')
    else:
        print('END!')
        break
```